# How to import certain Functions from type

Tags: haskell

I would like to import two functions from a module (RatOps) which are in the Datatype (type Rat). How can i do this without editing what is being exported in the module RatOps.

Comment: `import RatOps (Rat(attr1, attr2))`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the attributes `attr1` and `attr2` of the `Rat type with:

```
import RatOps(Rat(attr1, attr2))
```

If the `Rat` type is for example defined as:

```
data Rat = Rat {
    attr1 :: Bool
  , attr2 :: String
  }
```

you can import these as items from the `Rat` type.